# Eclipse Scala IDE: How to build standalone Scala app?

Tags: eclipse, scala, sbt

I am writing an app that uses AnormCypher (Cypher-oriented Scala library for Neo4j Server https://github.com/AnormCypher). I write my code in Eclipse Scala IDE. Using `sbteclipse` plugin I have imported AnormCypher sbt project into Eclipse. Next I have added it to Java build pass as external project. Everything compiles and works from Eclipse now.

*Question: How in Eclipse build a standalone Scala program with all necessary dependencies including external Scala project imported in Eclipse?*

Trying to create'executable jar' from Eclipse does not work in this case because to do so Eclipse requests "Select a 'Java Application' launch configuration to use to create a runnable JAR." Alas Eclipse here has no idea about Scala launch configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not currently a feature of the Scala IDE.

However, it's [easy](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/) to write a [simple build file](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Hello.html) for your project using [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/). Once there, you can use one of the numerous available plugins to create a distribution for it. Sbt has its own [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and [sbt-oneJar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) to create standalone JARs, and there is twitter's [sbt-package-dist](https://github.com/twitter/sbt-package-dist), with more varied publishing options.